# What's the point of Xcode and iOS version matching?

Tags: ios, xcode

We have a couple test iPhones in the office. The one I use for development hasn't been updated in the last couple months, the one used by our QA team has been recently updated, however. I'm also still using Xcode version 6.3, and my compilations run fine in the simulator or the dev iPhone.

However, now that the QA iPhone has been updated, my Xcode refuses to build for it, claiming that the verison of iOS on it (8.4) is not supported. This is a common occurrence and I've just been dealing with it. While I'm waiting for my Xcode to finish updating (which is taking its sweet time), I'm realizing that this limitation is arbitrary (or at least it seems that way). I've already compiled my app for the QA phone earlier this month, that version obviously wasn't built for 8.4, yet it runs fine on it. Likewise, other apps on the phone don't need to be redownloaded after each update, nor does the app store require recompilation for each iOS update. Clearly the newer version of iOS can support the app built by older version of Xcode, then why does Xcode refuse to deploy to a device that has been updated? Is there a checkbox I'm missing somewhere in build settings that says "deploy even if you don't recognize the iOS version"?

Comment: You might want to reword your title because the way it reads now, it sounds like what follows is going to be a rant, not an actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, is this better?

Comment: Yup, that quite a bit better.

Comment: Sure your app will run fine on the updated devices as long as the build settings allow it, but that isn't the question here. As for the versions support, given the amount of combinations of different sw and hw versions it isn't too bad of a practice to prepare a commonly available API that would let either side to reject connection rather than keep supporting tons of legacy features. One day you'll want to do something similar at your client-server application.

Answer (score 1):

I can build and debug on an iOS 9 iPhone with Xcode 6.4

Also you need to understand (but I'm not an expert either) that when there's an OS update, to really support debugging Xcode needs to be familiar with that OS' debugging symbols (which may change at every software update). This is why, when you plug in an older version of iOS (or any version it is encountering for the first time) Xcode will take a few seconds to load and process the device's symbols. That's my understanding of it.